# Python - Store marriage information using classes

Tags: python, class, family-tree

I am using the code from the answered question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671119/how-to-create-family-tree).

What would be the most pythonic way to store information about marriage? I would like it to be possible to ask for self.husband or self.wife from any married person stored in a class, and ask for self.children from these recursively.

```
class Person:
    ID = itertools.count()
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None, level=0):
        self.id = self.__class__.ID.next() # next(self.__class__.ID) in python 2.6+
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.children = []

def createTree(d, parent=None, level=0):
    if d:
        member = Person(d['parent'], parent, level)
        level = level + 1
        member.children = [createTree(child, member, level) for child in d['children']]
        return member

t = createTree(my_tree)  # my_tree is the name of thedictionary storing parents and children. Need 'parent' key to become 'parents' key which stores a list of two people.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to come out with a good model by yourself, what you're looking at here is a directed graph. I'd use networkx to create the graph. This will give you a bunch of tools for searching through the graph, displaying, getting stats out of it. 
So you can create a person as a node and then create edges to the parents and children. You can add restrictions to the edges creation if you want later on.
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html